# How is possible to know ID of taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php page for ACF fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, id

I created custom post type and custom taxonomy. But I use ACF, and is need to get ID of current page
Post type is 'objects'. Custom taxonomy is "objects_category". And page name taxonomy-objects_category.php

This code no works

```
$two_cols_catalog_left  = get_field('two_cols_catalog_left');
echo $two_cols_catalog_left;
```

But this code works

```
$two_cols_catalog_left  = get_field('two_cols_catalog_left', 47);
echo $two_cols_catalog_left;
```

47 - is ID of current page.

But is need to type

```
 $two_cols_catalog_left  = get_field('two_cols_catalog_left', $page_id);
 echo $two_cols_catalog_left;
```

How is possible to get ID of current page?

Comment: In order to get use `get_field` without a post ID parameter you need to be within the "loop". So ensure you've initiated the loop when you're using it and you wont need to manually get the ID.

Comment: Check out [get_queried_object_id](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$term = get_term_by( 'name', 'Дома 5, 'category' );
echo $term->term_id;
```

Comment: If you're already on the taxonomy archive page though there must be a better way to do this than looking up the term from the database.